# Enum and Switch statement C++

Tags: c++, oop, enums, switch-statement

```
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
enum operation {add, sub, mul, div};
        operation d;
        switch (d)
        {
        case add : cout << "addition of two numbers is: " << a + b << endl;
            break;
        case sub : cout << "subtraction of two numbers is " << a - b << endl;
            break;
        case mul : cout << "multiplication of the two numbers is " << a * b << endl;
            break;
        case div : cout << "division of the two numbers is " << a / b << endl;
        default: cout << "invalid parameters" << endl;
        }
```

when I build this, I get the error "uninitialized local variable d used", but when I initialize the variable to one from the defined list, I cannot choose any other switch case other than the one defined. 
I know I'm missing something, I googled a lot but couldn't get help. I'd really appreciate if anyone would help. Thank you!

Comment: When you enter the switch, the variable d must have been assigned some value. Ponder this.

Comment: @kapardhi where would the value of d come from ? .  You can initialise d with default value and read operation value ( add/sub/..._ from standard input and convert it into enum.

Comment: Switch doesn't generate any user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is making your code dynamic. Unfortunately, you are doing it completely wrong. Please first clear your concept on `enum`.

If this is the case, then you can try this-

```
int a, b;
char op;

cin >> a >> op >> b;

switch(op)
{
    case '+': cout << "addition of two numbers is: " << a + b << endl; break;
    case '-': cout << "subtraction of two numbers is " << a - b << endl; break;
    case '*': cout << "multiplication of the two numbers is " << a * b << endl; break;
    case '/': cout << "division of the two numbers is " << a / b << endl; break;
    default: cout << "invalid operator" << endl;
}
```